# Intuition behind intersection of subspaces with common basis vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $u$, $v$, $w$ be vectors in $\Bbb R^3$ such that $V = \operatorname{span}\{u, v\}$ and $W = \operatorname{span}\{u, w\}$ are planes in $\Bbb R^3$. Find $V \cap W$ if
>
> (a) $u$, $v$, $w$ are linearly independent.
>
> (b) $u$, $v$, $w$ are not linearly independent.

For both parts in this question, I present the intuition behind my method and some workings I have attempted to layout.

---

> (a) $u$, $v$, $w$ are linearly independent.

**Intuition**

At a glance, we know from this fact that none of the vectors in $\{u, v, w\}$ are linear combinations of the other vectors in the same set. Geometrically, this translates to having two planes in $\Bbb R^3$ which intersect along a line. Hence, intuitively we know that $\dim(V \cap W) = 1$.

**Working**

Take any $a \in V \cap W$. It is clear that

$$a \in V \cap W \implies a \in V \ \land a \in W.$$

Since $V = \operatorname{span}\{u, v\}$ and $W = \operatorname{span}\{u, w\}$, we have

\begin{align}
a &= c_1u + c_2v \\
a &= d_1u + d_2v
\end{align}

for $c_1, c_2, d_1, d_2 \in \Bbb R$.

Since $u$, $v$, $w$ are linearly independent, this means that

$$(c_1 - d_1)u + c_2v - d_2w = 0$$

has only the trivial solution $\implies c_1 - d_1 = c_2 = d_2 = 0$.

Hence $a = c_1u = d_1u$, so

$$V \cap W = \operatorname{span}\{u\}.$$

---

> (b) $u$, $v$, $w$ are not linearly independent.

**Intuition**

(I am more unclear on this portion of the question, please do correct my thinking if there are any flaws/mistakes.)

Given that $u$, $v$, $w$ are not linearly independent, by the definition, this means that every vector in $\{u, v, w\}$ can be expressed as a linear combination of the other vectors. In other words, $v = c_1u + c_2w$ for some $c_1, c_2 \in \Bbb R$. By this logic, geometrically we should obtain two planes that lie on each other, that is, $\dim(V \cap W) = 2$.

**Working**

Suppose $u$, $v$, $w$ are not linearly independent. By the definition, the system

$$c_1u + c_2v + c_3w = 0$$

has non-trivial solutions (not all $c_1, c_2, c_3 = 0$) and $c_1, c_2, c_3 \in \Bbb R$.

Expressing $v$ in terms of $u$, $w$:

$$v = - \frac {c_3} {c_2} w - \frac {c_1} {c_2} u.$$

Hence,

\begin{align}
\operatorname{span}\{u, v\} &= \operatorname{span}\left\{u, - \frac {c_3} {c_2} w - \frac {c_1} {c_2} u\right\} \\
&= \operatorname{span}\{u, w\}.
\end{align}

So

\begin{align}
V \cap W &= \operatorname{span}\{u, w\} \\
&= \operatorname{span}\{u, v\} \\
&= \operatorname{span}\{v, w\}.
\end{align}

Are my workings/ideas correct? Any advice would be greatly appreciated! (I recognize that my expression of ideas is rather hand-wavy, and hence would appreciate clearer ways of thinking about the particular concepts involved.)

Comment: Why can you divide by $c_2$?  Not all zero is not the same as all not zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reminds me of the time Bill Jacob drew hands waving on the board.

At first glance I think you got the first part.

As for the second, what if $v=w$. Then your last equality doesn’t hold. I think you are right about the dimension though, the intersection must have dimension two.

If $\{u,v,w\}$ is not linearly independent, then we must have that $\{v,w\}$ is dependent. That is, $v$ and $w$ are multiples of each other.

Comment: Good catch on the $v = w$, slipped my mind on that. Thank you!